# t-test for binary dependent variable?

Tags: r, t-test, likert

I am analyzing an experiment with a binary dependent variable (choice of the subjects). Afterward, subjects reported some measures on 5-point Likert scales. How do I test whether those measures influenced the choice? Is the t-test appropriate? Because the grouping factor is the dependent variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A t-test compares the means of a continuous dependent variable between two groups. The independent variable is binary. You have a binary dependent variable and an ordinal independent variable, so a t-test would not be appropriate.

You could use binomial regression (e.g., logistic regression) and treat your independent variable either as continuous or categorical. If you treat it as categorical, you ask whether the proportion of people who made the choice differs for each level of the measure (e.g., do people who gave a 5 on the measure have a different proportion of people who made choice A than do people who have a 1 on the measure?). If you treat it as continuous, you ask whether the proportion of people who made choice A varies linearly (or specific forms of nonlinearly) based on their value of the measure. Logistic regression is complicated and would require training, especially for someone who has uncertainty about using a t-test.

Comment: wouldn't a chi-sq or mcnemar test be the more appropriate suggestion for someone looking to do a hypothesis test.